# Changing the pixel size of a heat map

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, heatmap

I have created a heatmap with `pcolor()` of **matplotlib**, but its size in pixel is too small. How can I change the size of the heatmap plot to have a better resolution?

The python code is as follows:

```
plt.pcolor(short_ma,long_ma,results_pnl)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: the plot]

Comment: add `plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))` before calling pcolor.

Comment: The resolution of the image only depends on how you calculated the parameters `short_ma,long_ma,results_pnl`, but you didn't include that calculation in your code.

Comment: Harish Vutukuri solution works for me. Thanks